# How to prove that for element $c\in R,\ c^2=c \Rightarrow c\in C(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an associative ring. Let $C(R)=\{a\in R: ab=ba\; \forall b\in R\}$. Let $a^2=0 \Rightarrow a=0\; \forall a\in R$. How to prove that for element $c\in R,\ c^2=c \Rightarrow c\in C(R)$?

Comment: Let $x, y\in R$ and try your conditions on $x+y\in R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c \in R$, such that $c^2=c$. Let $b \in R$. Note that 
$$(c(b-bc))^2 = cbcb-cbcbc-cbc^2b+cbc^2bc = cbcb-cbcbc-cbcb+cbcbc = 0$$, so $c(b-bc) = 0$, i.e. $cb = cbc$.

Analogously get $((b-cb)c)^2 = 0$ and $bc = cbc$. Thus $bc = cb$.